# ALTER all stored procedures in database (add comment header template)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'd like to add the following template to the start of all stored procedures as part of a documentation policy, eg:

```
---------------------------------------------------
--- PURPOSE:
---
--- UPDATED BY --- UPDATED DATE --- DESCRIPTION----
---
---------------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to do this in some way, eg, loop through all stored procedures in the database and ALTER them ?

Comment: You could programmatically get stored proc definitions from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`, modify the text, and use `EXEC` to alter them.  This will get you started:  `SELECT r.ROUTINE_SCHEMA, r.ROUTINE_NAME, r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r
WHERE r.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in a few steps by scripting them and using Find & Replace:

1. Right click the database name in Management Studio and navigate to **Tasks > Generate Scripts**
2. On the **Choose Objects** page, filter the items you are scripting to **Stored Procedures**
3. On the **Set Scripting Options** page, select **Save to new query window**
4. Go through the steps and click **Finish**

This will script all of your stored procedures to a query window.

Then use find and replace to update the scripted procedures. As we plan to **ALTER** the stored procedures, we need to replace **CREATE** with **ALTER** and also add your comment block before **ALTER**:

1. Set **Find what** text to **CREATE procedure**
2. Set **Replace with** text to your comment block + **ALTER procedure**, noting the line breaks `\n`, which are required as the replace field isn't multi line.

> ---------------------------------------------------\n--- PURPOSE:\n---\n--- UPDATED BY --- UPDATED DATE ---
>   DESCRIPTION----\n---\n---------------------------------------------------\nALTER
>   procedure

In the **Find Options**, tick **Use** and select **Regular Expression** to enable the replacing of line breaks.

Click **Replace All**, check the script and then execute to alter them all.

**Caveat:** I've done this in SSMS 2012. From a [quick search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) I believe the scripting options are similar in 2008, but some of the highlighted terminology might be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it and you can create a loop that alters the variables.

```
DECLARE @CommentToAdd varchar(255)
DECLARE @VariableTextOption varchar(255)
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max)
SET @VariableTextOption = 'some random'
SET @CommentToAdd = '/* This is the header that says ' + @VariableTextOption+ CHAR(13) + 'stuff */ ' + CHAR(13)
```

--The string manipulation removes existing comments and changes the CREATE instruction to ALTER

```
SET @SQLString =  (SELECT @CommentToAdd + 'ALTER ' + RIGHT(r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION, (LEN(r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) - CHARINDEX('PROCEDURE', r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 0)+1)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES r WHERE r.ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' and ROUTINE_NAME = 'test')
exec (@SQLString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is quite old and has been answered already but I think my answer is much more complex and may be handy for future users.

**Remember to backup db before apply below script.**

```
-- declare variables
DECLARE @OBJ_COUNT INT,
    @COUNT INT = 0,
    @OBJ_NAME NVARCHAR(128),
    @OBJ_DESC NVARCHAR(128),
    @TEXT VARCHAR(MAX),  
    @FINAL_TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- declare table variables
DECLARE @HELPTEXT TABLE(Val VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @OBJECTS TABLE(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, ObjName NVARCHAR(128), ObjDesc NVARCHAR(128))

-- insert into @@OBJECTS all objects you want to alter
INSERT INTO @OBJECTS
SELECT NAME, TYPE_DESC
FROM sys.all_objects
-- change below to SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE only if you do not want to add comment to functions and triggers
WHERE TYPE_DESC IN ('SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','SQL_TRIGGER', 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION', 'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION')
 -- include only user objects
AND is_ms_shipped = 0 
-- you can filter to apply changes only to few objects
--AND NAME LIKE '%MY_STORED_PROCEDURES%'

-- get objects count
SET @OBJ_COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @OBJECTS);

-- loop through objects 
WHILE (@count < @obj_count)
BEGIN
    -- increment 
    SET @COUNT = @COUNT + 1;
    SET @TEXT = N'';

    -- get current object name and type
    SELECT @OBJ_NAME = ObjName,
        @OBJ_DESC = ObjDesc
    FROM @OBJECTS 
    WHERE ID = @COUNT

    -- get current object description
    INSERT INTO @HELPTEXT
    EXEC sp_HelpText @OBJ_NAME;

    SELECT @TEXT = COALESCE(@TEXT + '' + Val, Val)
    FROM @HELPTEXT;

    --PRINT @TEXT       -- for debug purposes

    -- clear table
    DELETE FROM @HELPTEXT;

    -- alter object if has no comment already
    IF @TEXT NOT LIKE '%/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%'
    BEGIN
        -- changed create to alter
        IF (@OBJ_DESC = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')
        BEGIN
            SET @TEXT = REPLACE(@TEXT, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
        END
        ELSE IF (@OBJ_DESC = 'SQL_TRIGGER')
        BEGIN
            SET @TEXT = REPLACE(@TEXT, 'CREATE TRIGGER', 'ALTER TRIGGER')
        END
        ELSE -- one of two types of function ('SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION', 'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION')
        BEGIN
            SET @TEXT = REPLACE(@TEXT, 'CREATE FUNCTION', 'ALTER FUNCTION')
        END

        SET @text = 
'/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name        :   ' + @OBJ_NAME + '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- UPDATED BY --- UPDATED DATE --- DESCRIPTION
---                                                                                                                 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/'
+ CHAR(13) + 
@TEXT

        -- initially @TEXT is VARCHAR(MAX) to handle huge objects, but to sp_executesql we must pass NTEXT, NCHAR or NVARCHAR only,
        -- so we need to case in below line...
        SET @FINAL_TEXT = CAST(@TEXT AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
        --select @final_text    -- for debug purposes
        --print @obj_name       -- for debug purposes

        -- final update/alter object
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @FINAL_TEXT
    END
END
```